# How do you emit generic events in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a component library in Angular(9). I want to build a button component that takes an event type as a property and then emits that type when the button is clicked.

My understanding of how custom events in Angular work is:

Child declares an `EventEmitter`

```
  @Output() buttonClicked = new EventEmitter<Event>();
```

Parent binds to that event (which you can then respond to)

```
<my-component (buttonClicked)="buttonClicked($event)"></my-component>
```

What I'd like to do is something like this. Of course the syntax is wrong, but to give you an idea:

```
  // custom button class
  @Input() eventType: string;
  @Output() [eventType] = new EventEmitter<Event>();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply emit the eventType with the event itself? this.buttonClicked.emit(this.eventType);

Comment: @Carsten My understanding is, the component that's responding to the event has to bind to the name in the `Output` property?

Comment: I think it's unclear to me what your end goal is. Why do you have an Input string where the output has to get the same name? You want your users to declare the name of the output?

Comment: Well, in this example, I'm going to eventually have an app using various instances of custom button that only emits one event when any of them are clicked. I'm starting to realise that perhaps the thing to do is to do as you say and pass the event type with the event and then check that value in each handler.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Angular doesn't allow us to use generic types for our `@Input` or `@Output`. You of course can write something like `@Output() eventType = new EventEmitter<T>();`, but there's will not be a chance to pass the `<T>` to the component's class.

Angular uses AOT (Ahead Of Time) compilation under that hood, so it cannot know what kind of dynamic data you would like to pass inside of the component in the future.

The only thing you can do here it's to use `any` type:

```
@Output() eventType = new EventEmitter<any>();
```